# Pandas: changing the row indices to column indices. Or Vice versa

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, plot, melt

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'start':[1,2,3],'zone':['a','b','c']}); 
df['end']=[4,5,6]
df.set_index('zone',drop=True,inplace=True,append=False)
print(df)

      start  end
zone            
a         1    4
b         2    5
c         3    6
```

I would like to modify this dataframe to become:

```
zone  a              b            c
      start  end     start  end   start  end
      1        4     2      5     3      6
```

By changing the row indices to column indices. I need this because I want to melt the dataframe later, so it would become a long table. But I do not know how to melt the row index along with the column index. But getting this output would allow me to simply use:

```
pd.melt(df)
```

To get the long table.
If there is a way to change the column indices to row indices, I could then skip the step where I change the row indices to column indices, and get the long table straight away.

Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this using `stack`,`to_frame`, and T for transpose:

```
df.stack().to_frame().T
```

Output:

```
zone     a         b         c    
     start end start end start end
0        1   4     2   5     3   6
```

Answer (score 2):

Reconstruct from array manipulation and multi index construction.

```
pd.DataFrame(
    df.values.reshape(1, -1),
    columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df.index, df.columns])
)

      a         b         c    
  start end start end start end
0     1   4     2   5     3   6
```